# Attempted relative import in non-package

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

I have the following structure in my project:

```
+main_proj

    +modules
        +user_ops
            -add_user.py
            -remove_user.py
            -__init.py
    +common
        -user_operations.py
        -__init__.py
    -main.py
    -__init__.py
```

My problem is that `add_user.py` and `remove_user.py` both depend on `user_operations` and when I try to call them, I get a `relative import in non-package` error.

**Main.py**

```
from common import user_operations as user_operations  #This works ok

if __name__ == '__main__':

    command = "remove_user"

    #Load usage, functions and paths to modules
    __doc__, function_dictionary, modules = utilities.load_modules()

    #Get function from dictionary
    func = function_dictionary[command]

    #Execute function
    result = func(api_root, arguments, simulate, headers)
```

**The module that gets called by `func(api_root, arguments, simulate, headers)`**

**remove_user_front.py**

```
from ...common import user_operations as user_operations

    def remove_user_front(api_root, arguments, simulate, headers):

        #Get users in this account
        users = user_operations.get_users(api_root, arguments["<source_account>"], headers)

        #This is smelly
        if arguments["--id"]:
            type = "id"
        elif arguments["--username"]:
            type = "username"
        #End smell

        result = remove_user(api_root, arguments["<source_account>"], arguments["<user_id>"], type, simulate, headers)

        if not result:
            return False
        else:
            return True

    function_dictionary = {"remove_user" : remove_user_front}
```

**Error**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensio
ns\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.0\visualstudio_py_util.py", line 7
6, in exec_file
    exec(code_obj, global_variables)
  File "C:\Users\mryan\Documents\Code\cli\cli_front.py", line
 70, in <module>
    recovery.start_recovery(recovery_file, auto_recovery, headers, modules)
  File "C:\Users\mryan\Documents\Code\cli\recovery.py", line 1
01, in start_recovery
    imported_module = imp.load_source('recovery',module)
  File "C:\Users\mryan\Documents\Code\cli\modules\cam_ops\
remove_user_front.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ...common import user_operations as user_operations
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```

Does anybody know how I can keep my file structure and enable modules under `modules` to use modules under `common`?

Comment: Did you try to use the `-m` switch? To launch `add_user`: `python -m main_proj.modules.add_user`, obviously you should do this when you are outside of the `main_proj` directory.

Answer (score 2):

When your application starts up it get's an os.path attributed.

Each modules that will try to import anything will have that same path. It means that your files in common that will need to import something out of user_ops will need to import it like if it was your main.py which would import them.

try

```
from modules.user_ops import add_user
```

in your user_operations

Comment: I think I got it working by adding:

`import common.user_operations as user_operations`

To the top of my `remove_user_front.py` and `add_user_front.py`